# How to access prev or next array at foreach blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I currently develop a blade View that will loop an array from Controller.

I just create a table that have an aspects, detail aspects, current status, and remark. So, I want loop (with foreach) at my blade view, then at my array there will be a condition that aspects have same value in next row.

For table example:

```
Aspects     | Detail Aspects | Current Status | Remark
Curriculum  |       1        |      Good      |  Good
Curriculum  |       2        |      Good      |  Good
Curriculum  |       3        |      Good      |  Good
Teaching    |       4        |      Good      |  Good
```

So for the table, I want to check `if prev.Aspect == current.Aspect`, so I don't need to print it again, or maybe I can rowspan that .

I already using $index at my foreach, but I only can print it as number, not accessing my `Obj[index]` value.

Here my blade  code :

```
<table border='1'>
        <tr align='center' class='header'><td>Aspects</td><td>Details</td><td>Current Status</td><td>Remark</td></tr>
        @foreach($prAspect as $index => $data)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$data->praDesc}}</td>
                <td>{{$data->prsDesc}}</td>
                <td>{{$data->currentStatus}}</td>
                <td>{{$data->remark}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `for` loop instead :

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($prAspect); $i++)
    // use $i as index
    // use $prAspect[$i]
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `->toArray()` to your query builder when you fetch the data. This will help your purpose in this case to access the items as an array for easier comparison.

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr align='center' class='header'><td>Aspects</td><td>Details</td><td>Current Status</td><td>Remark</td></tr>
    @foreach($prAspect as $index => $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$data['praDesc']}}</td>
            <td>{{$data['prsDesc']}}</td>
            <td>{{$data['currentStatus']}}</td>
            <td>{{$data['remark']}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it might help

```
@foreach($prAspect as $index => $data)
     <tr>
        <td>{{!$loop->first ? $prAspect[$index- 1]->praDesc : $data->praDesc}}</td>
        <td>{{!$loop->first ? $prAspect[$index - 1]->prsDesc : $data->prsDesc }}</td>
        <td>{{!$loop->first ? $prAspect[$index- 1]->currentStatus : $data->currentStatus }}</td>
        <td>{{!$loop->first ? $prAspect[$index- 1]->remark : $data->remark }}</td>        
   </tr>     
@endforeach
```